# What were German contingency plans in case Hitler was killed?

Tags: nazi-germany, germany, hitler

There were several attempts to kill Hitler, most famously probably the [20 July plot](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/20_July_plot).

So… what would have happened, if that e.g. succeeded?

Now, as I do not want to ask a question about alternative histories and speculations, let me clarify the question a little:

- Were there any plans by Hitler of who would follow him if he died?
- Was there any "crisis squad" or people who were responsible in that case?
- Did they even think of that/accounted that or thought this would never happened?
- Is there any indication that this would have caused a crisis or problems/unrest in the population?
- Were there any indications by others e.g. close to Hitler that could have adopted power?
- Can one estimate how much disruption would have caused that? Nearly nothing with just someone following up or could it e.g. have shortened World War II?

So of course one cannot say what would have happened, but surely there must have been some "backup plan" or so? Or one could estimate how important he was for Nazi Germany and whether he could have been easily "replaced"…

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because "What if" questions are off-topic here.

Comment: I explicitly tried to address that in the question: I mostly want to ask about the backup plans/things that were planned for that case. There must have been some documents, "risk assessment" or so that allow one to not just speculate, but base this one facts.

Comment: @rugk You're asking 6 or 7 different questions here, if which the first couple are historically answerable, the rest slide into 'what-if' speculation.

Comment: I thought this had already been [answered](https://history.stackexchange.com/q/50275/1401) on SE. Hitler was an autocrat; there were no plans.  There were technical successors, but no succession plan.  Hitler *was* the state.

Comment: @MarkC.Wallace So the SS, the Wehrmacht, the Abwehr, etc. all had no contingency plans?  That seems ... surprising.

Comment: @sempaiscuba Think of what would've happened if Hitler found out someone had made such a plan.

Comment: @MarkCWallace I think you have the right answer. Hitler stayed in power by playing his top henchmen against each other.

Comment: @Spencer  Hitler may have been deluded but, AFAIK, he didn't actually believe himself to be immortal.  As long as the plans didn't formally name a successor I suspect it wouldn't have been an issue.  They'd probably have called them "Plans to preserve the Fuehrer's legacy" or some such nonsense, but contingency plans are what the military do.  If none of the German military institutions had drafted such contingency plans, then that is interesting in itself.

Comment: In the inter-war years, US contingency planners came up with [War Plan Red](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/War_Plan_Red) _just in case_ there was a war with the British Empire.  They probably also have similar plans in case of a war with the [Duchy of Grand Fenwick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_Fenwick) (or its nearest real-world equivalent).  Planning for things that _might_ happen (or that _will_ happen) is their job.  The German military also had contingency planners, so the question is, did the Allies capture any of those plans & did those plans include what to do when Hitler died?